# What is the value of $\tan (\frac{\pi}{2} - \epsilon)$?

Tags: trigonometry, infinitesimals

$$\tan(\frac{\pi}{2}-\epsilon)$$

By epsilon I mean an infinitesimal.

Comment: What are you trying to do? $\tan\frac{\pi}{2}=\infty$. You have $\tan(\frac{\pi}{2}-\epsilon)\approx \frac{1}{\epsilon}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $\epsilon$, $$\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\epsilon\right)=\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\epsilon\right)}{\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\epsilon\right)}=\frac{\cos \epsilon}{\sin \epsilon}=\cot \epsilon.$$ For small $\epsilon$, this can be approximated as $\frac{1}{\epsilon}-\frac{\epsilon}{3},$ since $\cot\epsilon\approx\frac{1}{\epsilon}\frac{1-\epsilon^2/2}{1-\epsilon^2/6}\approx\frac{1}{\epsilon}\left(1-\frac{\epsilon^2}{2}+\frac{\epsilon^2}{6}\right).$

Comment: This answer is the correct one if OP really meant the word "infinitesimal" rather than intending to imply some kind of limiting process.

Comment: @PatrickStevens : I don't see why, since infinitesimal means a limiting process.. (in particular we avoid the $\mathcal{O}(1)$ term and lower terms when there is an $1/\epsilon$ term). and the worst part is that $\cot \epsilon \sim 1/\epsilon$ is not an answer, since he doesn't explain how one would know that.

Comment: @user1952009 Fixed.

Comment: @user1952009 An infinitesimal is some positive quantity which is smaller than all positive reals. See non-standard analysis, for instance.

Comment: @PatrickStevens : yes I know, and $1/ \epsilon$ is greater than all positive reals

Comment: @user1952009 But you say "infinitesimal means a limiting process". I don't see how that fails to contradict "an infinitesimal is a positive quantity which is smaller than all positive reals", given the Dedekind completeness of the reals.

Comment: @PatrickStevens : you don't see the limiting process with "smaller than every real" ? and my problem was that $\epsilon = \epsilon + \epsilon^2$ in the same way that $1/\epsilon + \epsilon = 1/\epsilon$

Comment: @user1952009 But $\epsilon \not = \epsilon + \epsilon^2$ unless you're working with a specific kind of infinitesimal (namely a nilpotent one), and not all systems of infinitesimal work that way. Robinson's infinitesimals are not nilpotent, for example.

Comment: @PatrickStevens : clearly $\cot \epsilon \ne \frac{1}{\epsilon}$ if $\epsilon+\epsilon^2 \ne \epsilon$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38441/discussion-between-patrick-stevens-and-user1952009).

Answer (score 2):

You mean $$\tan \left( \frac{\pi}{2} - \epsilon \right) \sim \frac{1}{\epsilon} \quad \text{when } \epsilon \rightarrow 0$$

### Explanation

Used $$\tan(x) = \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)} \approx \frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2}-x}$$

by doing a taylor expansion about $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$ separately for the sine and cosine.

Then use $x=\frac{\pi}{2}-\epsilon$ to get your answer.

If used a higher order taylor series you also get

$$\tan\left( \frac{\pi}{2}-\epsilon \right) \approx \frac{\epsilon^2-2}{2 \epsilon} \approx \frac{3 ( \epsilon^2-2)}{\epsilon (6-\epsilon^2)} $$

Comment: and this is valid for $\epsilon > 0$ or $\epsilon < 0$ (or even for $\epsilon$ complex when considering $\tan(x) = -i\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{e^{ix}+e^{ix}}$), and why don't you write $\tan(\pi/2-\epsilon) \sim 1/\epsilon$ when $\epsilon \to 0$  instead of $\approx$ ?

Comment: Cause I am an engineer and not a mathematician. To me it is an approximation.

Comment: $\tan(\pi/2-\epsilon) \sim 1/\epsilon$ when $\epsilon \to 0$ means that $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{\tan(\pi/2-\epsilon)}{1/\epsilon} = 1$, it is what you meant. $\approx$ just means that "in some case we can consider they are almost equal" but without any further rigorous precision.

Comment: Thanks. I'll keep it in mind.